# How to throw an underflow exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In C# I can throw an overflow exception:

```
throw new System.OverflowException("Cannot push onto a full stack.");
```

How do I throw an underflow exception?

```
throw new System.UnderflowException("Cannot pop from an empty stack.");
```

It doesn't look like `UnderflowException` is a method of `System`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be technically still be an OverflowException as you are trying to access from a index greater than available?

Comment: @Staeff no, it's trying to access the index `-1`

Comment: In this case you should create own exceptions

Comment: Also note that Microsoft is using the InvalidOperationException when you are trying to do that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9say334k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: An overflow exception is defined as _**"The exception that is thrown when an arithmetic, casting, or conversion operation in a checked context results in an overflow"**_ - nothing to do with stacks.

Comment: @minseong that's an IndexOutOfRange exception. It's the same exception that .NET would throw if you tried to access an array with an index value of -1. If you intend to throw the *same* exception, why don't you let .NET do its job? Or simply rethrow the exception eg after logging?

Comment: Do NOT use `OverflowException` to represent a stack overflow. It is specifically (and documented as) being for arithmetic overflows. If you must have a custom exception for stack overflow and underflow, create your own exception classes called `StackOverflowException` and `StackUnderflowException`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `UnderflowException`. If you do following:

```
var stack = new Stack();
stack.Push(1);
var x1 = stack.Pop();
var x2 = stack.Pop();
```

You will get `InvalidOperationException` :

> Stack empty.

But you completely free to create your own `Exception` class:

```
public class UnderflowException : Exception
{
    public UnderflowException(string message): base(message)
    {           
    }
}
```

and throw it if you need:

```
throw new UnderflowException("Could not pop from empty stack");
```

Comment: I have to create my own implementation of a  stack for CS class. My teacher wants me to throw underflow and overflow exceptions

Comment: @minseong This is kind of stupid, but then just create them yourself

Comment: @Staeff I know this is kind of stupid. I have talked with my teacher about it but she's adamant

Comment: @maksin-simkin UnderflowException should probably also extend ArithmeticException, as does OverflowException: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @minseong that's *neither* overflow *nor* underflow. That's an index out of range situation. In fact, you shouldn't use OverflowException either, since it has a very specific meaning that isn't applicable here. Inherit from `IndexOutOfRange` if you want

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your own empty Exception and throw that:

```
public class UnderflowException : Exception
{

}
```

Then in your function:

```
throw new UnderflowException();
```